# How do I allow the user to change plot shape size from inputs in Pinescript?

Tags: plot, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to write this plotshape so that the user of the indicator on TradingView can choose their own size for each of the plotshape signals that occur. So for instance, for a certain signal that plots, I want the user to be able to choose a size for the plotshape. Here is the code I am working with:

```
    shapeSizeInput = input.string("default", title="Label Size",
         options=["very small", "small", "default", "large", "very large"])
    
    shapeSizeOption = switch shapeSizeInput
        "very small" => size.tiny
        "small"      => size.small
        "default"    => size.normal
        "large"      => size.large
        "very large" => size.huge
    
    plotshape(x2_cross_long, title = "X2 Cross Long", style=shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar, color=color.blue)
```

I have the plotshape size left off for this right now. But I have tried connecting this switch satement with the string drop down menu of the inputs and connect that to the size portion of the plotshape. I'm not sure how to make that connection.

Am I supposed to create a new label or something? And if so, then how does that connect to my signal so the user can still change the style? I'm a little confused how to make this connection. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.

The `size` argument of `plotshape()` expects a `const string`. That means, its value must be known at compile time.

You are initializing that variable via an `input.*()` which makes it a `input string`.

You can read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Type_system.html#) to get to know the type system.

You either need to let the user change the size via the Style tab, or you can use a `label`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

shapeSizeInput = input.string("default", title="Label Size", options=["very small", "small", "default", "large", "very large"])
    
shapeSizeOption = switch shapeSizeInput
    "very small" => size.tiny
    "small"      => size.small
    "default"    => size.normal
    "large"      => size.large
    "very large" => size.huge

if (barstate.islast)
    label.new(bar_index, high, "▲", yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.new(color.white, 100), style=label.style_none, textcolor=color.blue, size=shapeSizeOption)
```

Comment: Thanks, that does help some. I copied your edit and put it in the script. I see the label now in the styles tab, but it does not connect with any of my signals I have plotted. Do I need to do something else to connect them? So when I have all my signal shapes plotted, I can change the label size, but it dos not change any of my shapes on the chart, am I missing something else? I also don't have the option to change colors either with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My code was just an example. It will put a label on the last bar. You should change `if (barstate.islast)` and put your condition there.

Comment: For the color and all other stuff, you need to create separate user inputs. They cannot be modified via the Style tab.